# Remapping z coordinates in opengl

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am writing a Starmap in OpenGL (current), but since the stars are at astronomical distances, they make the near/far settings too big.  These are intended to be accurate visualizations of true stars.  I tried to rescale the z values of the points in the vertex shader after going through the projection matrix, but it appears I still get them moving around due to the perspective divide.  Is there a way to rescale Z to fit within a smaller near/far range, without having the x/Y change in a perspective view?   Can I do something with the W coordinate?  Note that the stars are just a set of points.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you might want to read this : http://outerra.blogspot.fr/2012/11/maximizing-depth-buffer-range-and.html

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly possible to have a far plane at infinity. The GLM library provides a function `infinitePerspective` to create an appropriate projection matrix for such uses. Googling "projection matrix infinite" yields a lot of articles on the topic.

Comment: The problem is, I am looking at the Earth, and satellites, and want to have normal perspective (eg 30-45 degress FOV), and have a far distance of 100000 km.  Can I do both simultaneously, or would I need to use 2 different projection matrices (1 for stars, 1 for all else)

Comment: @DanHewett: You can do both in one single projection matrix, with a finite near, and an infinite distant far plane. How can this work? Imagine (or actually plot) the function `f(x) = 1/x`. Imagine the near plane being mapped so that `x(near) = 1` and `x(far→+∞) → +∞`. As you can see for the whole value range between `[near, +∞[` the resulting depth buffer values are in the range `]0, 1]`, which is exactly what you want.